# How to combine GROUP BY and ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER

Tags: sql-server

I Have

```
CusID Name Country PhoneNo
------------------

1     JOHN USA     555555
1     JOHN USA     555554
2     MIKE CANADA  111111
2     MIKE CANADA  122222
5     JOHN UK      888888
5     JOHN UK      888889
```

I want to display output like this:

```
CusID Name Country PhoneNo
------------------

1     JOHN USA     555555
                   555554
2     MIKE CANADA  111111
                   122222
5     JOHN UK      888888
                   888889
```

(or) any other methods in SQL?

Comment: Do it on the client side.

Comment: Can i get with SQL query?

Comment: yes. but if we have duplicate name with different ID, it's not worked!

Comment: It's the same problem, and the same solution. Just `OVER (PARTITION BY CusID, NAME, Country ORDER BY ...) `